Extending jQuery with toggleRow - Uncaught ReferenceError: isHiddenWithinTree is not defined?
Trying to duplicate the jQuery toggle() function but to use table-row instead of block as the display value.
I took the existing functions and added a jQuery.fn.extend() as defined below Note: I left showHideRow unmodified from the showHide for the test to ensure it would work as toggle() works now
<script src="/includes/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.fn.extend( {
    showHideRow: function( elements, show ) {
        var display, elem,
            values = [],
            index = 0,
            length = elements.length;

        // Determine new display value for elements that need to change
        for ( ; index < length; index++ ) {
            elem = elements[ index ];
            if ( !elem.style ) {
                continue;
            }

            display = elem.style.display;
            if ( show ) {

                // Since we force visibility upon cascade-hidden elements, an immediate (and slow)
                // check is required in this first loop unless we have a nonempty display value (either
                // inline or about-to-be-restored)
                if ( display === "none" ) {
                    values[ index ] = dataPriv.get( elem, "display" ) || null;
                    if ( !values[ index ] ) {
                        elem.style.display = "";
                    }
                }
                if ( elem.style.display === "" && isHiddenWithinTree( elem ) ) {
                    values[ index ] = getDefaultDisplay( elem );
                }
            } else {
                if ( display !== "none" ) {
                    values[ index ] = "none";

                    // Remember what we're overwriting
                    dataPriv.set( elem, "display", display );
                }
            }
        }

        // Set the display of the elements in a second loop to avoid constant reflow
        for ( index = 0; index < length; index++ ) {
            if ( values[ index ] != null ) {
                elements[ index ].style.display = values[ index ];
            }
        }

        return elements;
    },
    showRow: function() {
        return showHideRow( this, true );
    },
    hideRow: function() {
        return showHideRow( this );
    },
    toggleRow: function( state ) {
        if ( typeof state === "boolean" ) {
            return state ? this.showRow() : this.hideRow();
        }

        return this.each( function() {
            if ( isHiddenWithinTree( this ) ) {
                jQuery( this ).showRow();
            } else {
                jQuery( this ).hideRow();
            }
        } );
    }
} );

jQuery(function($) {
    $('.expandChildTable').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected').closest('tr').next().toggleRow();
    })
});
</script>

The error received was: Uncaught ReferenceError: isHiddenWithinTree is not defined?
I noticed I was using the .min version and though that must be it, so I redid things using the .min version as below (*Note: On this one I setup the correct display value to be table-row:
<script src="/includes/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery.fn.extend( {
    showHideRow: function( e, t ) {
        for(var n,r,i,o,a,s,u,l=[],c=0,f=e.length;c<f;c++)(r=e[c]).style&&(n=r.style.display,t?("none"===n&&(l[c]=_.get(r,"display")||null,l[c]||(r.style.display="")),""===r.style.display&&ee(r)&&(l[c]=(u=a=o=void 0,a=(i=r).ownerDocument,s=i.nodeName,(u=ne[s])||(o=a.body.appendChild(a.createElement(s)),u=ce.css(o,"display"),o.parentNode.removeChild(o),"none"===u&&(u="table-row"),ne[s]=u)))):"none"!==n&&(l[c]="none",_.set(r,"display",n)));for(c=0;c<f;c++)null!=l[c]&&(e[c].style.display=l[c]);return e
    },
    showRow: function() {
        return showHideRow( this, true );
    },
    hideRow: function() {
        return showHideRow( this );
    },
    toggleRow:function(e){
        return"boolean"==typeof e?e?this.showRow():this.hideRow():this.each(function(){ee(this)?ce(this).showRow():ce(this).hideRow()})
    }
}); 

jQuery(function($) {
    $('.expandChildTable').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('selected').closest('tr').next().toggleRow();
    })
});
</script>

However I still get: Uncaught ReferenceError: ee is not defined
Help!! Why can't it call those functions since jQuery is already loaded and my new functions are in the jQuery extension?
TIA!!
